# Trying to make an exit inventory button on coronasdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk, inventory

I am currently working on a game what requires an inventory system. I cannot work out how to make an exit button for a display object I created.

Here is my code :

```
local Choose_slot = display.newImage("Images/choose_slot.png")
 Choose_slot.x = centerX + 96
 Choose_slot.y = 45

function choose_slot:tap ( event )
  Inventory_Screen = display.newRect( centerX, centerY, 1500, 1500 )
  Inventory_Screen:setFillColor( 0.3, 0.3, 0.3 )
end

local Exit_Button = display.newImageRect( "Images/Exit_Image.png", 32, 32)
Exit_Button.x = centerX + 255
Exit_Button.y = centerY - 135

function Exit_Inventory:tap ( event )
    Inventory_Screen:remove()
    Exit_Button:remove()
end

Exit_Inventory:addEventListener( "tap", Exit_Button)

Choose_slot:addEventListener( "tap", choose_slot)
```

Just for your Information, "Choose_slot" is an image that brings up the inventory. I would like to make it so when the "Inventory_Screen" comes up the "Exit_Inventory" button pops up and when you tap it, it removes the "Inventory_Screen" and the "Exit_Button" from the screen and goes back to screen you were on before you clicked inventory!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The picture is what left after I changed your code to this:

```
function Choose_slot:tap ( event )  

        Inventory_Screen = display.newRect( centerX, centerY, 1500, 1500 )
        Inventory_Screen:setFillColor( 0.3, 0.3, 0.3 )

        local function handleExitBEvent( event )   -- ERROR IS BELOW! 

    if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then
        print( "Button was pressed and released" )
        print( "Removing Inventory!" )
        Choose_slot:removeSelf() -- This is not removing -- 
        ExitB:removeSelf()
        Inventory_Screen:removeSelf()
        Inventory_Slot1:removeSelf()
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked perfectly! I will add you to the game credits once done! But one question, is there any reason to remove inventory slot 1 or was that a mistake? thanks

Comment: Good luck with the game.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to this in a display group so you can remove all objects in a group with a line command.

Add the button and the function to your code as follows:

```
local function exitFunc(event)
    Choose_slot:removeSelf() -- add whatever you want to remove
    exitB:removeSelf() -- can use object.isVisible = false if you wanted but they maybe touchable still
end 

exitB= widget.newButton
{
  width=135,
  height=60,
  defaultFile = "whatever.png",
  overFile = "whateverOver.png",
  label = "Exit",
  onPress = exitFunc,
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding, I have attempted to use your code but I'm still having no luck. I am getting an error saying : "game:lua:72: attempt to index global 'widget' (a nil value). I am confused as I have clearly defined a widget in the code. could you help?

Comment: That is when one of your object is local but you accessing in a global place. Simply remove all your local keywords to see which one is the problem otherwise show the whole file so I can check.

Comment: Ok so this is my code : http://pastebin.com/EisBsNqx     -- the issue I am having is the widget part of the Inventory screen. I want it so when you tap an image on screen it takes you to the inventory screen, inside the screen is an exit button (the widget that doesn't work), the exit button can only appear when the inventory button is pressed. hope this helped you? also I need to make the exit button exit the inventory screen removing the button and the screen back to what you where on before you went on the inventory screen. thanks

Comment: Have you included local widget = require( "widget" ) in the beginning of your code? Your error is line 72, zip and email me the whole project amirfarazmand@gmail.com

Comment: Just checked, you have to add this   defaultFile = "Images/Exit_Image.png",
  overFile = "Images/Exit_Image_Over.png",

Comment: Is it clear? you forgot to add images fodler to your path

Comment: Ok, that fixed the issue and the button is fully working now, apart from the it is not removing the grey inventory_screen background. I have below a .zip of the whole game. I have quoted where the issue is. (It is the function that leads from the OnEvent on the button) thanks for your quick responses.     Link : http://www.filedropper.com/cavedwellerdevelopercopy         Thanks!

Comment: I tried it. The only thing not removed is your grey background which you need to add this under where you put the quote   Inventory_Screen:removeSelf()

Comment: Unless you want all slots to be removed meaning to add Inventory_Slot1:removeSelf() and so on